# How can I use GTK3 with perl?

Tags: perl, gtk, gtk2

How can I use GTK3 with Perl? Is it already possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't believe it is possible yet although the best place to ask would be the [gtk-perl-list](http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gtk-perl-list).

As I understand it, the future of Perl bindings for Gtk is using the gobject-introspection API to automate as much as possible.  Work is progressing in this area but I'm sure help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Gtk3 is released ... most of the API remained unchanged .. GLade is not wokring right now .. have to build new Glade module to work over GTK3 ..

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpbWyymqLo8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpbWyymqLo8)